# Update a column based on other column with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id  integer
sumqty numeric
maxqty  numeric
```

The columns `id, sumqty` are updated by other functions regularly.
I need to write a function that pass on these two columns and update the `maxqty` column.

for example:

```
id, sumqty, maxqty
5    20
5    70
5    45
3    20
1    12
1    2.5
```

after function runs, desired output will be:

```
id, sumqty, maxqty
5    20      45
5    10      45
5    45      45
3    20      20
1    12      12
1    2.5     12
```

I wrote this code:

```
update A set maxqty= (select MAX(sumqty)  OVER (PARTITION BY id))
```

but it doesn't always works. Sometimes it doesn't give me the actualy MAX.

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Create a view instead, and you'll never have inconsistent data. (Or use triggers.) It's generally a bad idea to store calculated data (from other columns.)

Comment: OK but still, why it doesn't produce the MAX as expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use correlated subquery instead:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb220/3/1)**

```
UPDATE mytable t1
SET maxqty= (SELECT MAX(sumqty) 
             FROM mytable t2
             WHERE t1.id = t2.id );
```

Result:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ id  ║ sumqty  ║ maxqty ║
╠═════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  5  ║ 20      ║     45 ║
║  5  ║ 10      ║     45 ║
║  5  ║ 45      ║     45 ║
║  3  ║ 20      ║     20 ║
║  1  ║ 12      ║     12 ║
║  1  ║ 2.5     ║     12 ║
╚═════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

More efficient way:

```
WITH cte AS
( 
  SELECT id, MAX(sumqty) AS sumqty
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY id
)
UPDATE mytable m
SET maxqty = c.sumqty
FROM cte c
WHERE m.id = c.id;
```

Your original query:

```
update mytable 
set maxqty= (select MAX(sumqty)  OVER (PARTITION BY id);
```

Gives:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦════════╗
║ id  ║ sumqty  ║ maxqty ║
╠═════╬═════════╬════════╣
║  5  ║ 20      ║ 20     ║
║  5  ║ 10      ║ 10     ║
║  5  ║ 45      ║ 45     ║
║  3  ║ 20      ║ 20     ║
║  1  ║ 12      ║ 12     ║
║  1  ║ 2.5     ║ 2.5    ║
╚═════╩═════════╩════════╝
```

It is because `UPDATE` works per row. And your subquery has only one row to process not bunch of them.

Comment: isn't PARTITION BY id should gives all rows of that id?

Comment: @SMW Think about it as `UPDATE mytable SET maxqty = (SELECT MAX(sumqty) OVER(PARTITION BY id) FROM (SELECT id, sumqty, ... ) AS sub);`. You have only one row to process.

Comment: yes but the : SELECT MAX(sumqty) OVER(PARTITION BY id should pass on all rows of that id

Comment: OK. is there a way to speed up this querry? when I add it the function becomes very slow. i have over a milion records in the table.

Comment: @SMW added update with CTE. Why do you use function?

Comment: @SMW Great to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
update mytable 
set maxqty=t.max 
    from (select id,max(sumqty) from mytable group by id) t
where t.id=mytable.id
```

<kbd>[`SQLFIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb220/11)</kbd>